# Passing sensitive information in the req object Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, next.js, koa

I am an ex-PHP Laravel developer and I am trying to explore other options right now, currently using `Node.js`, `Sequelize`, `Koa` and `Next.js` to build a small app.

When sequelize is initialized, a `models` folder gets created automatically and it has along the lines the following code.

```js
...
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    console.log('Filer file: ', file)
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
...
```

Which is working fine when imported in the main `server.js` file.

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to include this in any of the other files, in my case I need to have access to it via the newly release API routes from Next.js `/api/{endpoint}` (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction).

If I import the file there `__dirname` (from the main sequelize models file) is the root directory of my machine which makes me think that if this code is automatically generated code by their CLI tool I am probably doing something wrong.

One way I found to make this work is by passing the `db` object via the `req` object in the `server.js` file.

```js
  router.get('/api/*', async (ctx) => {
    /**
     * There has to be a better way
     */
    ctx.req.db = db
    await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
    ctx.respond = false;
    ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
  });
```

Is there better way to handle all of this?